# how to get this Simple regular expression to work in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm a regex newbie

I'm trying to remove all occurrences of `\n` & `\s\s` (double white space) and `,` (comma)

This is my program

```
import re;

text = "this is a cool thing to do,         \n blah"

re.sub('(,|\\n|\s\s)','',text)

print text;
```

But this doesn't replace anything.
What should i fix?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: @BrenBarn I get the same string back

Comment: Please share the expected output. I checked it out and it works as expected.

Comment: @rickydj I forgot to capture the return variable from re.sub

Answer (score 3):

`re.sub` does not modify its input.  It returns a new string.  If you want to replace the original string, assign the result back to the original variable:

```
text = re.sub('(,|\\n|\s\s)','',text)
```

Comment: ya forget to see  the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the return from `re.sub` to a new string as follows:

```
import re

text = "this is a cool thing to do,         \n blah"
new_text = re.sub('(,|\\n|\s\s)','',text)

print '"' + text + '"'
print '"' + new_text + '"'
```

Also, you do not need to add `;` to the end of those two lines in Python.

Which gives:

```
"this is a cool thing to do,         
 blah"
"this is a cool thing to do blah"
```